# Matching JS Objects by Key, Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a consolidated JS object based on values within two seperate JS objects. Each JS objects shares a "key" and I want to find the values of each based on matching keys.

For example, I have to JS objects:

```
     cpuData.push({
            id:         myData.d.results[i].ID,
            name:       myData.d.results[i].Name,
            description: myData.d.results[i].Description,
            deviceId:     myData.d.results[i].DeviceItemID,
            avgCPU:       cpuAvg,
            maxCPU:       cpuMax,
            minCPU:       cpuMin
         });
```

And

```
      memoryData.push({
        id:         myData.d.results[i].ID,
        name:       myData.d.results[i].Name,
        description: myData.d.results[i].Description,
        deviceId:     myData.d.results[i].DeviceItemID,
        avgMem:       memAvg,
        maxMem:       memMax,
        minMem:       memMin          
        });
```

What I want to do is to create a NEW object (finalResults[]) which would contain the avgCPU, avgMem, and deviceID where the deviceID is the same within both objects.

I tried this using nested for loops and also looked at various key, _, etc. functions but I don't quite see how I can pull this off.

```
       for (i=0; i < cpuData.length; i++) {
           for (j=0; j < memoryData.length; j++) {
                if (memoryData[j].deviceId = cpuData[i].deviceId) {
                       finalResults.push({
                           deviceId:     memoryData[j].deviceId,
                           cpuComponentId: cpuData[i].id, 
                           memComponentId: memoryData[j].id, 
                           avgCPU:       cpuData[i].avgCPU,
                           avgMemory:    memoryData[j].avgMem 
                       });
                  }
             }
        }
```

The problem is that I am getting duplicates for the outer loop when multiple inner loop matches occur. For example, if there are multiple memoryData.avgMemory values for a given deviceID, than I am getting multiple object entries for each memoryData.avgMemory that include redundant cpuData,avgCPU values.

Ideally a single object for each distinct deviceID that includes 1 or more avgCPU and avgMemory values (arrays are fine).

Comment: Create an array of found deviceID's - when you match one, push the ID to the array and check that array on every loop.

Comment: Your "if" has just one "=", would you mean "==" ?

Comment: well spotted queval_j

Comment: or === if they are all of the same type.

Comment: Good catch queval_j! missed that! Cleaned up my results significantly but I am still getting multiple entries. I'm going to give tymeJV's suggestion a go

Comment: Just to close the loop, implemented the suggestion from tymeJV and it works perfectly ;)